# running sass --watch results in deleting the css file

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, css

running (Dart) SASS 1.19.0
installed via

```
brew install sass/sass/sass
```

In terminal (following the [Sass documentation](https://sass-lang.com/guide)) from within the desired directory, if I run

```
sass styles.scss styles.css
```

or

```
sass --watch styles.scss styles.css
```

it results in deleting the styles.css file.  What do I need to do in order to compile my scss sheets through terminal without additional software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the error message in terminal I was able to determine that the SCSS was not properly nested.  I had written it like:

```
div {
    p {
    color: $paragraphColor;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: $paragraphBackgroundColor;
    }
}
```

when it should have been:

```
    p {
        color: $paragraphColor;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background: $paragraphBackgroundColor;
    }
}
```

After correcting the format, running:

```
sass styles.scss styles.css
```

in terminal worked.